# Factorial Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have searched the site, and though it has been answered many times, I still have one more question.

I have the code to do the factorial with recursion. I am just having trouble with the easiest part of it.

When printing, my project requires that it should print:

```
4! is equal to 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24
```

How do I get a `for` loop, or recursive way to get the `"(4 x 3 x 2 x 1)"` to work with any value of n?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print(num+ "!"+ " is equal to ");
        Print(num);
        System.out.print(FactorialCalc(num));
    }

    public static double FactorialCalc(int number)
    {
        double result;
        if(number<=1)
        {    
            result= 1;                  
            return result;
        }    
        else
        {
            return result= number * FactorialCalc(number-1);
        }
    }

    public static void Print(int n)
    {
        for(int i=n; i<=0;i--)
        {
            System.out.print(n + 'x' + (n-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Which is the variable used for counting the iterations of the `for` loop in the `Print` method? What are its values inside the loop?

Comment: You're asking how to produce the actual `Z! is z x (z-1) x (z-2) ... x 1` output?

Comment: `for(int i=n; i<=0;i--) <--` this loop condition is wrong.

Comment: Marc B yea, i just need to produce that, the code functions properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void Print(int n) {
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.print("=");
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print("x");
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Enter an integer:
4
4! is equal to 4x3x2x1=24.0
```

Comment: @Vigan glad i was able to help.

Comment: The only "enhancement" I would add is an error message if the number entered is negative.  Other than that, you got my vote!

Comment: Yep, this is correct. Good luck when your teacher is going to ask what `continue` means (and why it's there) ;)

Comment: Oops!  By definition, 0! = 1 and this code does not print that out. that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using a for loop will be

```
int fact=1;
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
fact=fact*i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, you only forgot one thing:

Which is the variable used for counting the iterations of the for loop in the Print method? What are its values inside the loop?

```
public static void Print(int n)
{
    for(int i=n; i<=0;i--) //i minor or equal 0? When does the loop need to finish?
                           //What happens if you multiply something with 0?
    {
        System.out.print(n + 'x' + (n-1));
    }

}
```

Try to get it on your own, but if you can't...

> ...the problem is that you're printing `n` instead of `i`.  In the loop, the variable that is decremented is `i` via `i--`. It starts from `num` and gets smaller and smaller... That's what you need to print!
>
> Changhe the print to:
>
> `System.out.print(i + "x");`
>
>  Your task is to get rid of the last printed `x`! ;D
>
>  As per the loop condition, your loop must stop when `i` reaches 1 to have
>
>  (num) x (num-1) x .. x 2 x ***1*** (no 0!!)
>
>  So the condition will be `for(int i = n; i >= 1;i--)`

Comment: `i < = 0` is a bad a conditional ontop of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate printing the list of multiplied values directly into the recursion rather than adding a looping print.  Put appropriate `print()` statements in both the `if` and `else` clauses of your recursion.  For the former, just print `"1 = "`.  For the latter, print `number + " x "`.

You don't actually need the local variable `result`.  I'd also recommend using Java conventions regarding capitalization: method names should begin with a lower case letter, upper case indicates a class or interface.  Finally, I changed the return type to `long` because factorials are integer-based, even though they can quickly get big.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
   public static long printFactorial(int number) {
      if(number <= 1) {    
         System.out.print("1 = ");
         return 1;
      } else {
         System.out.print(number + " x ");
         return number * printFactorial(number-1);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
      int num=keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.print(num + "! is equal to ");
      System.out.println(printFactorial(num));
   }
}
```